# LinkageError when trying to run Java-project in jdk 18.0.1.1

Tags: java, linkageerror, java-18

I have launched a project which was currently running in `jdk 17.0.3`, in the new `jdk 18.0.1.1` and got the following error:

```
Fehler: Beim Laden der Klasse launching.Main ist ein LinkageError aufgetreten
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: launching/Main (class file version 61.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 62.65535
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, and the preview features are also enabled for the new version. (Both in the vm args and the .settings-file). Playing around with the jre-settings hasn't helped, and I'm afraid to break something.

Comment: If you use preview features, make sure that the `--release` option is the same version as the JDK you want to run it on.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn The --release option is on, but I find no eclipse-settings that specify the version.

Comment: The settings are all on the same page, right where the “Use '--release' option” and “Enable preview features” toggles are, there’s the “Compiler compliance level” setting. But to use preview features of JDK 18, you need specific support for targeting JDK 18 from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the newest version of eclipse did the thing, as the old one wasn't supporting jdk18.